# React/ES6 reduce object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following object that holds workouts for specific days:

```
{
  "2019-03-02": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "workout_day": "2019-03-02",
        "title": "Swimming",
        "description": "",
        "completed": true,
        "points": 5
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "workout_day": "2019-03-02",
        "title": "Running",
        "description": "",
        "completed": false,
        "points": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "workout_day": "2019-03-02",
        "title": "Rowing",
        "description": "",
        "completed": true,
        "points": 3
    },
  ],
 "2019-03-05": [...]
}
```

I want to get a new object that shows for each day how many workouts exist, how much of them have been completed and a sum for the points, like so:

```
{
  "2019-03-02": {
    "workouts": 3,
    "workouts_completed": 2,
    "total_points": 8
  },
  "2019-03-05: {...}
}
```

However, I'm totally stuck at the moment. Thanks for help!

Comment: Please share your attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will reduce your data into the one you want to transform to

```js
const data = {
  '2019-03-02': [{
      id: 1,
      workout_day: '2019-03-02',
      title: 'Swimming',
      description: '',
      completed: true,
      points: 5
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      workout_day: '2019-03-02',
      title: 'Running',
      description: '',
      completed: false,
      points: 0
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      workout_day: '2019-03-02',
      title: 'Rowing',
      description: '',
      completed: true,
      points: 3
    }
  ],
  '2019-03-03': [{
      id: 1,
      workout_day: '2019-03-02',
      title: 'Swimming',
      description: '',
      completed: true,
      points: 7
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      workout_day: '2019-03-02',
      title: 'Running',
      description: '',
      completed: false,
      points: 0
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      workout_day: '2019-03-02',
      title: 'Rowing',
      description: '',
      completed: false,
      points: 3
    }
  ]
}

const reducedData = Object.keys(data).reduce((acc, key) => {
  acc[key] = {
    workouts: data[key].length,
    workouts_completed: data[key].reduce((acc, item) => {
      if (item.completed) return acc + 1
      return acc
    }, 0),
    total_points: data[key].reduce((acc, item) => {
      return acc + item.points
    }, 0)
  }
  return acc
}, {})

console.log(reducedData)
```

Answer (score 2):

You've multiple solution to achieve this. Here is one that combined [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) + [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

```
Object.entries(input).reduce((acc, [date, workouts]) => {
  const completed = workouts.filter(workout => workout.completed);

  return {
    ...acc,
    [date]: {
      workouts: workouts.length,
      workouts_completed: completed.length,
      total_points: completed.reduce((acc, workout) => acc + workout.points, 0),
    }
  };
}, {});
```

Note that `Object.entries` is not available in all the major browsers.

Answer (score 1):

This does the job.

I used `Array.prototype.reduce` and destructuring with default values.

```js
var data = {
  "2019-03-02": [{
      "id": 1,
      "workout_day": "2019-03-02",
      "title": "Swimming",
      "description": "",
      "completed": true,
      "points": 5
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "workout_day": "2019-03-02",
      "title": "Running",
      "description": "",
      "completed": false,
      "points": 0
    }, {
      "id": 3,
      "workout_day": "2019-03-02",
      "title": "Rowing",
      "description": "",
      "completed": true,
      "points": 3
    },
  ],
  "2019-03-05": [{
      "id": 1,
      "workout_day": "2019-03-02",
      "title": "Swimming",
      "description": "",
      "completed": false,
      "points": 0
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "workout_day": "2019-03-02",
      "title": "Running",
      "description": "",
      "completed": false,
      "points": 0
    }, {
      "id": 3,
      "workout_day": "2019-03-02",
      "title": "Rowing",
      "description": "",
      "completed": true,
      "points": 8
    },
  ]
};

var result = {};

for (let key in data) {
  result[key] = data[key].reduce(({
        workouts = 0,
        workouts_completed = 0,
        total_points = 0
      }, currentValue) => {
      return {
        workouts: workouts + 1,
        workouts_completed: currentValue.completed ? workouts_completed + 1 : workouts_completed,
        total_points: total_points + currentValue.points
      };
    }, {});
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have your object that holds workouts for specific days in an object called `json`, you can use `Object.keys()` to iterate over all the keys.  Then you can `map` over this and get the workouts for one specific day at a time. You can then use that to create an object for each day.  To calculate stuff like `totalPoints` you'll use `reduce` to sum up the total points.

```
Object.keys(json).map(key => {
    return {
        [key]: {
            workoutsCompleted: json[key].length,
            totalPoints: json[key].reduce((accum, workout) => accum + workout.points, 0)
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 const result = {};

 for(const [workout_day, entries] of Object.entries(input)) {
   result[workout_day] = { 
     workouts: entries.length,
     workouts_completed: entries.reduce((acc, e) => acc + e.completed, 0),
     total_points: entries.reduce((acc, e) => acc + e.points, 0),
  };
}
```

`Object.entries` is quite useful for mapping objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = {
  "2019-03-02": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "workout_day": "2019-03-02",
        "title": "Swimming",
        "description": "",
        "completed": true,
        "points": 5
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "workout_day": "2019-03-02",
        "title": "Running",
        "description": "",
        "completed": false,
        "points": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "workout_day": "2019-03-02",
        "title": "Rowing",
        "description": "",
        "completed": true,
        "points": 3
    },
  ],
 "2019-03-05": []
};

function makeReport (report, workout) {
  return {
    workouts: report.workouts + 1,
    workouts_completed: workout.completed ? report.workouts_completed + 1 : report.workouts_completed,
    total_points: report.total_points + workout.points
  };
}

const out = Object.entries(data).reduce(function (report, [date, workouts]) {
  return {
    ...report,
    [date]: workouts.reduce(makeReport, { workouts: 0, workouts_completed: 0, total_points: 0 })
  };
}, {});

console.log(out);
```

which logs:

```
{ '2019-03-02': { workouts: 3, workouts_completed: 2, total_points: 8 },
  '2019-03-05': { workouts: 0, workouts_completed: 0, total_points: 0 } }
```